# How to not change position of elements when position set fixed

Tags: html, css

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="landingpage.css">
        <title>Landing Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div class='navbar'>
            <div class='left-section'>
                <p class='name'>Balls</p>
            </div>
            <div class='middle-section'>
                <a href="#"><p>WHY BALLS</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>REVEIWS</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>ABOUT</p></a>
                
            </div>
            <div class='right-section'>
                <p>LOG IN</p>
                <button class='free-trial'>FREE TRIAL</button> 
            </div>
            
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

I'm trying to make a fixed nav bar .The position: fixed is in the .navbar class. When I put position: fixed, the words overlap in the navbar but if you didn't put it, it works perfectly and it doesn't overlap. How do I fix this? Btw, my design only works with full screen because the words overlap.

```css
body {
                margin: 0px;  
                margin-bottom: 1000px   
            }

            p {
                font-family: Arial;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            a {
                font-size: 11px;
                margin-right: 20px;
                color: black;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                text-decoration: none;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            .middle-section {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-evenly;
                flex:1;
                width: 100px;
                margin-left: 10px
                
            }

            .navbar {
               display:flex;
               align-items: center;
               position: fixed
            }

            .right-section {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-evenly;
                width: 200px
            }

            .left-section {
                
            }

            .name {
                font-weight: 600;
                margin-left: 20px;
                font-size:20px;
            }

            .free-trial {
                background-color: white;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-color: black;
                width: 200px;
                height: 40px;
                vertical-align:middle;
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin-left: 30px;
                margin-top: 3px;
            }

            

This is the code with the error. If you want to see the desired output, remove the position: fixed from css code
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="landingpage.css">
        <title>Landing Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div class='navbar'>
            <div class='left-section'>
                <p class='name'>Balls</p>
            </div>
            <div class='middle-section'>
                <a href="#"><p>WHY BALLS</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>REVEIWS</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>ABOUT</p></a>
                
            </div>
            <div class='right-section'>
                <p>LOG IN</p>
                <button class='free-trial'>FREE TRIAL</button> 
            </div>
            
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to give width:100% to your .navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to create a header with the nav-bar.
If yes,I suggest using position:sticky for the nav-bar!

```css
.nav-bar{
           position:sticky;
           top:0px;
           text-align:center;
           background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div class=nav-bar>
Header
</div>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
Where can I get some?

There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc...
    
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It will be at the top of the screen even if page is scrolled down.

Comment: Tyyy. It worked. I was missing, top: 0px. What does 'top' do?

Comment: top basically sets the position of the element..
so if top:0px it means place my element 0px away from the top most position.

Comment: Ohh ok. But the navbar was already at the top. Why do i need to set it again for it to work? @DeeTee

Comment: It must be set explicitly for the browser to override the default values...